# Parsing apart a decimal into two integers in either Stata or Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I'm working with a dataset that has really terrible ID numbers that are an integer followed by a 13 digit decimal. However, the first 6-7 decimal places are zeroes. For example:

```
10.0000000960554
```

This is making my life difficult. So I want to parse the IDs apart at the decimal into two integers, drop the leading zeros, and put them back together as one giant integer. However, everything I find for how to do this in Excel keeps the numbers after the decimal after the decimal. For Stata, I've tried to convert the numeric into a string so I can then parse it, but Stata won't let me because it's a decimal:

```
encode  ScrambledID, generate StringID
```

Here's the error:

```
not possible with numeric variable
r(107);
```

An added issue, I can't just split the decimal in Excel and then multiply by 1e+12 because it messes with the values (long story with how they were derived).

Like I said, I'm fine with doing this in either Stata or Excel. Either way this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Pedantic comment: You need `generate()` for a legal `encode`. The parentheses are needed. This doesn't affect the problem you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel:

In one column put:

```
=int(A1)
```

In the next put:

```
=--MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,999)
```

As @Grade'Eh'Bacon stated, I have use a few shortcuts in the above formula.  The `--` at the beginning change text that are numbers into numbers.  It replaces the `VALUE()` function.

The `999` is a superfluous number in that it is assumed the length of the string being split is not longer than 999 characters.  It can be replaced with the `LEN()` function which would return the actual length of the string.

So putting the two together:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

Where A1 is the location of the number

[image]

Comment: Consider using LEN([String]) instead of 999, and also VALUE instead of -- to convert the text to a number, to be more explanatory - ie: =VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(".",A1)+1,LEN(A1))

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon both would work great.  I have a tendency to find the fewest keystrokes to get what is desired.  But I see your point on it being easier to understand.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I added your recommendations with an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your story is truly shocking.

I'd advise extreme caution in any software. For a start, numbers with decimal parts will be rendered differently depending on whether they are imported as 4-byte or 8-byte reals, in Stata terms as `float`s or `double`s. The underlying problem is that many decimal numbers have no exact binary representation.

In Stata terms, `encode` is indeed out of the question for a numeric variable (and your example would also fail for other reasons). But ideally you should import the identifiers as strings in the first place. Otherwise you should try a conversion such as `generate stringID = string(numid, "%16.13f")`.

```
. di %21s string(10.0000000960554, "%16.13f")
     10.0000000960554

. di %21s string(10.00000009605539, "%16.13f")
     10.0000000960554

. di %21s string(10.00000009605544, "%16.13f")
     10.0000000960554

. di %21s string(10.00000009605535, "%16.13f")
     10.0000000960554
```